# Kaddish Without Minyan

Tags: halacha, kaddish, minyan

Can you ever say Kaddish without a Minyan?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35324/759

Answer (score 4):

You can say Kaddish without a Minyan if when you started *Chazaras Hashatz* you had a Minyan and someone left in middle you keep going and even say Kaddish!!!

Comment: True, but how about a source (and a link, pretty please?)

Comment: Rema O.C. 55:3.

Comment: By the way, at Shacharis you can even say the kaddish after uva letzion which is also linked to the tfillah

Comment: @YDK Not everyone agrees that you can say two Kaddishes. Some say if you want to say the one after Uva Letzion then you should skip the one after Tachanun.

Answer (score 3):

Just to clarify...if you had a minyan for the silent amida and then the tenth walked out so that you are left with 9 you may say chazarat hashatz (repetition), and say kaddish shalem after uva le'tzion but you may not say chatzi kaddish after tachanun nor may you take out the torah and read @user146 is correct, I would also add arukh hashuhan who talks about when the tenth person leaves.

I would also add that the Shulkhan Arukh cites a yesh omrim that allows for all devarim she'bikedusha (things which require a minyan) to be done with 9 and a katan who is holding a chumash or 9 plus a sefer torah.  Most dont use this even in a shaas hadachak but many will rely on this in the shaat hadahak situation.

rema 55:4 ואפילו על ידי חומש שבידו אין לצרפו. מיהו יש נוהגין להקל בשעת הדחק 
and even if the minor is holding a chumash it is fobidden to include him. However there are those who are lenient in a shaat hadahak (instance of dire need)

the rema is citing based on the RO"Sh and the Hagahos Maimoniyos and the Mordechai

Comment: I seem to recall he says nine plus a _katan_, irrespective of what the _katan_ is holding. Can you cite your version of nine plus a _katan_ holding a _chumash_ (or mine)?

Comment: @msh210 the shulkhan arukh does not make a mention of the need for a chumash but the rema would require it if it is to be used at all.

Comment: Note that our printed books aren't actual "chumashim" in the classical sense.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Kaddish L'yachid ("Kaddish for an individual") attributed to ninth-century Rav Amram Gaon.

Comment: Seemingly this isn't the kaddish the OP was asking about

Comment: Please add the text and where it can be found.