# Is there such a thing as a Kaddish L'vatola?

Tags: halacha, kaddish

In [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35182/4794) there is a reference to a Kaddish that is better left unsaid as it is a Kaddish L'vatola.

Kaddish does not seem to have anything in it which cannot be said in a vacuum.  Is there any reason to not say Kaddish other than the possibility that it doesn't accomplish anything and would be a possible waste of time?

I am not asking about whether Amen should be responded to such a Kaddish.  I am asking if there would be any reason for the Kaddish itself to not be said.  This could be relevant for a chazzan to practice singing Kaddish, or just to sing Kaddish to myself because I like the tune.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20022&st=&pgnum=15

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76463/759

Comment: Note that that "reference" is not sourced.

Comment: Perhaps a better reference than an unsourced answer would be a *sefer* that [actually says that](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33777&st=&pgnum=30).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Nishmas Yisrael Page 469 at the bottom](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=10133&st=&pgnum=105) brings in the name of Shaalos U'Teshuvos Maharshag that there is no issue of Bracha L'Vatala in Kaddish since there is no mention of Hashem's name in it.

Comment: So it can be said in private also? (The asker asks about that, too ("to sing Kaddish to myself because I like the tune").)

Comment: But is there an issue of _Kaddish_ L'Vatala?

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 11):

While the Nishmas Yisrael (pg 469) believes that there is no issue, quoting the Maharshag (Teshuvah 2:40), he himself notes that, if so, one should be able to say kaddish without a quorum of ten. This seems to me to be an opinion that is very much in the minority, even though he himself seems to only think that R. Chaim Abulafia disagrees.

Really though, the Kenesset Hagedolah (Or Hahayyim 55) states that one should not say 'kaddish' more than necessary, and this is quoted by the Aruch Hashulhhan (55:3-4) and Mishnah Berurah (55:1), Kaf Hahayyim (55:8), and the Ben Ish Hai (Vayehhi 9). The reason given is because the Kaddish is considered a high praise to Hashem of a significant level of holiness and therefore shouldn't be taken lightly. (The 'necessary' number of kaddishes, and whether that number depends on the amount of mourners who want to say kaddish, is a separate issue.)

(Sidepoint: The reason for requiring a minyan, according to the Bach (88), Hida (Birkei Yosef 88:3), Taz (88:1), Kaf Hahayyim (55:7), and Mishnah Berurah (55:2) is because the Kaddish is a [*davar shebikdusha*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13817/3483).)