# Answering Amen to kaddish for a dog

Tags: halacha, tefilla, death, animals, kaddish

I once attended a synagogue regularly where a particular congregant was infatuated with his dog. Upon the passing of the dog the congregant began to say kaddish. He was unclear of his reasons for saying kaddish but it was clear to those who knew him that he intended to say it in the honour of his dog.

Can others answer?

Comment: Is he saying the kaddish to sanctify God?

Comment: @DoubleAA maybe if he is dyslexic

Comment: I wonder if he intends to say Kaddish for 11 months...or longer/shorter if he was a REALLY good dog?  It seems to prompt a question "How long should I say Kaddish for my dog?" but I have a feeling it would be downvoted ruthlessly...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Per [Maariv](http://www.nrg.co.il/online/11/ART2/476/252.html) quoting Chadrei Chadarim quoting Rabbi Shteinman Shlita there is no problem answering Amein if one says Kaddish on his dog.

> "האם מותר לענות אחרי קדיש כזה (לכלב), אמן ואמן יהא שמיה רבא?", נשאל
>   הגראי"ל על ידי תלמידיו, בעקבות פנייה של אדם שביקש להגיד קדיש על כלבו
>   שנפטר - כך על פי אתר האינטרנט החרדי בחדרי חרדים.
>
> הגראי"ל חייך והשיב: "הרי אם היה אומר קדיש בלא כל סיבה, ודאי שהיו עונים
>   אחריו אמן, אם כן מדוע שטפשותו תגרע את המצב? מה אכפת לנו שהוא חושב על
>   הכלב...אין בכך כלום".

Comment: Why would you answer amen to a kaddish being said for no reason?

Comment: @YEZ Is it being said to sanctify God?

Comment: @DoubleAA Your implied argument makes sense, but is not implied by Rav Steinman's (apparent) words. He appears to be saying it really doesn't matter at all _why_ you were saying it. All that matters for the answerer is that _he_ is promoting God's name.

Comment: @DoubleAA What he said ^^^.  בלא כל סיבה does not seem to indicate "to sanctify God"

Comment: @YEZ Adderabba! Someone who isn't trying to sanctify God via saying kaddish is missing the point so badly that perhaps amen shouldn't be said. בלא כל סיבה there is referring to what prompts the person to want to sanctify God.

Comment: @DoubleAA You had a private conversation with R' Shteinman or somehow extracted this from the above?

Comment: @YEZ We were talking on the level of what his words "seem to indicate".

Comment: @DoubleAA I understand that. What I don't understand is how the unqualified words "for no reason" seem to mean "for a lofty reason, but motivated by nothing."

Comment: @YEZ תרי גווני reason.

Comment: @gershongold This addresses answering.  As far as saying it in the first place, I'm assuming you would apply a previous answer of yours, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35326/4794, but maybe worth adding here.