# Should you answer Kadish s'fayka?

Tags: chazzan-prayer-leader, kaddish, minyan, amen

If someone is making a minyan which you beleive doesn't have the required ten people, he says that guy will answer but you see that he most likely will not, and all together you highly doubt whether it's a legit minyan.

He starts the minyan and is saying Kadish and borchu. Should you not answer?

Comment: Is the case where you have a Safek if it's a Minyan (eg. one of the members is only Safek Jewish bc they were mixed up at birth) or where you hold there is no Minyan but the Chazan holds/thinks there is?

Comment: Both ..........

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35324/759

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R' ovadya yosef writes:

אין להתיר לומר קדיש וברכו ושאר דברים שבקדושה הנאמרים בעשרה, סמוך לקברות צדיקים, מבלי שיהיה שם מנין של עשרה אנשים. ואין לסמוך בזה על דברי אגדה לומר שצדיקים במיתתם קרויים חיים, (כמבואר בברכות יח:), לצרפם למנין. שמכל מקום אפילו על דוד מלך ישראל אמרו (שבת קנא:) במתים חפשי, כיון שמת אדם נעשה חפשי מכל המצות. וממילא אין לצרף למנין צדיקים שנפטרו. לפיכך יש למחות באלה הנוהגים לומר קדיש ליד קברי הצדיקים והוריהם, בערב ראש חודש ניסן ובערב ראש חודש אלול, אפילו אין שם מנין של עשרה אנשים. ואם עברו ואמרו קדיש, אין לענות אמן אחריהם, שהיא בכלל אמן יתומה. [ילקו"י מהדורת תשס"ד, ספר על הל' פסד"ז, סי' נה הע' י' עמוד שסא, שאר"י ח"ב עמ' צט].

Whats understood from this is that when there isn't minyan a person shouldnt answer amein.

Comment: In the case in the Teshuva there aren't actually 10 people. The question is about when there are 10 live (Jewish?) bodies, just they aren't all paying attention.

Comment: I doubt that when im davening I need to make sure that all the participants are answering amein...