# Is it permissble to practice parts of davening that require a minyan to be recited?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, chazzan-prayer-leader, minyan

Generally, an individual may not recite certain sections of the prayer service that are considered "holy" such as Kaddish, barchu, kedusha, chazaras hashatz unless he is part of a minyan.

Would one be permitted to practice these sections if he needed to practice to act as ball tefila

To further clarify this question. This is with not changing Gd's name to "Hashem", "Elokeinu", or any other substitute for Gd's name in Hebrew.

Comment: I see no reason why someone can't practice any part of the prayer service, as long as he doesn't use G-d's name when it involves a bracha. How else is a professional *chazzan* supposed to practice? Besides, what do you think happens during a *chazzan's* interview, esp. for the High Holidays?

Comment: Some things like kadish don't use any if Gd's names and wood it be different if it was someone who is practicing just to learn verses someone doing this for a living?

Comment: partial dupe of [This M.Y. question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35324/5275)

Comment: Are you referring to practicing while saying God's name? Or by using a nickname like "Hashem"? Probably worth clarifying in the question by [edit]ing

Comment: @double if I were refeeing to using Hashes when applicable (except for example kadish makes no use of Gd's name) instead of using the proper name there wouldn't be a question.

Comment: @laser depends how much you know about Judaism. I don't know you, and most people definitely have no clue. So best to be clear in the question post

Answer (score 1):

This will be a partial answer, for now, until I can address all the various parts of the prayer that your question implies.

First of all, I am citing (with some editing) from this [M.Y. answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/13817/5275):

> The mishna in Megillah 23b e gives these examples of things that
>   require a minyan meaning at least 10 males >= age 13:
>
> - Having a chazzan (this includes kaddish, barchu, prisah al hashema and chazarat hashatz)
> - Reading the Torah portion
> - Reading the Haftorah
> - Having the Kohanim bless the people

The term "reading of the Torah" is defined by Rash"i on that Talmud page as בצבור - meaning the requirement to read the Torah when there is a congregation. Thus, if one is not part of a congregation, one is not performing this function. Thus, a Bar Mitzvah boy as well as those doing *Shna'im Mikra Echad targum* as examples, may do this without a minyan b/c it doesn't fall under that requirement / definition at all. Logically, I assume that the requirement for Haftarah meets the same definition, thus one may practice the haftara.

[This question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35324/5275) addresses whether one may say Kaddish without a minyan.

Comment: leining can be made different by using a tikun instead of sefer Torah and not saying the brachos before and after. Also saying pasukim from tanach doesn't inherently require a minyan unlike parts of davening such as barchu, kadish, and kedusha

Comment: The linked question is addressing saying kadish as a prayer but not for practice for example

Comment: @Laser123 Read the 3rd paragraph in the body of the linked question regarding Kaddish. The answers, there, address the question regarding whether one can say Kaddish without doing it as part of prayer.