# Congregation without a Minyan

Tags: shabbat, tefilla, synagogue, chazzan-prayer-leader, minyan

What parts are to be omitted in *davening* if the congregation does not have a *minyan*? I know *Kaddish* and *Borchu* need a *minyan*, but what about things like the *Chazzan*'s repetition of the *Amidah*? (Although I believe that needs a *minyan* though.)

Since the term "*davening*" is a broad term, how about focusing mostly on *Shabbos tefillos*.

Comment: This is a superset of these: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1946/3 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9802/3 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18972/3

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9797/organized-prayer-in-the-synagogue-with-less-than-10-people-community-or-not

Answer (score -1):

Kaddish, Barchu, the Chazzan's repetition of Shemoneh Esrei, in some instances the Torah and Haftoroh readings, and the last 2 paragraphs of Yikum Porkan Menshimayah.

Comment: Can you please explain "some instances the Torah and Haftorah"?

Comment: 2nd Yakum Purkan and all misheberach lakahal

Comment: Public reading of the Torah definitely requires a minyan. I believe that Shulchan Aruch, among other places, describes this. Haftarah, I'm uncertain about, actually. Though, perhaps, there is a direct connection that there is no haftarah without a preceding Torah reading? BTW, it's a given that if there is no Torah reading, you would omit the prayers related to the Torah service itself. Also, for those who include "13 Middot" as part of tachanun, I believe that is omitted when there is no minyan, or it must be recited with the proper trope notes.

Comment: Also (I mean: in addition to what @Jakub said), please [edit] in sources for your claims.